# I want to setup Jenkins with bitbucket for incremental deployment to Salesforce

Tags: jenkins, salesforce, bitbucket, incremental-build

I want to enable jenkins to do delta deploykets to Salesforce using Bitbucket as the SCM.

Currently the setup deploys the complete branch that has been configured in Jenkins.

I am very new to Jenkins and need assistance in getting this setup.

TIA
PK

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Delta deployments are related to multi layered applications. Do you need just deploy new changes in bitbucket to your Salesforce servers?